# React - redux state changes but component is not displaying updated state object property

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am running into an issue with state changing and component not updating. All my research is pointing to mutate state improperly but I am using **redux-toolkit** to mutate change so I am unsure where the problem is. I am using typescript for my code.

I can confirm that state is mutating in 3 phases. When the component is initially rendered the useEffect hook kicks off, state is changed via setting **isLoading** to true. When the API call completes, the state is updated again causing the component to re-render. I am only selecting specific items from the state for now - ingredients and pagination.

The odd part is that the component correctly displays the list of ingredients but the value for **pagecount** (in pagination property from state) is not being picked up.

Specifically these two lines of code come across as undefined. When I log the entire object out ({console.log(pagination)}) I do see the correct values being logged after re-renders. Why is the property for pagination coming through as undefined between all re-renders? It's even undefined at the beginning of page load (before useEffect hook) even though its explicitly set in initial state.

```
<Pagination count={pagination.totalPages}

<p>page count: {pagination.totalPages}</p>
```

Above

```
const ingredients: Ingredients[] = [];
const pagination: XPaginationDto = {
  currentPage: 1,
  pageSize: 5,
  totalCount: 0,
  totalPages: 0,
  nextPageLink: "",
  previousPageLink: "",
};

const initialState = {
  ingredients,
  isLoading: false,
  errorMessage: "",
  pagination,
};

export const getIngredientsAction = createAsyncThunk(
  "ingredients/getIngredients",
  async (options: RequestOptionDto, { dispatch }) => {
    try {
      const response = await ingredientsApi.getIngredients(options);
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(getIngredientsFailure(e));
    }
  }
);

const ingredientSlice = createSlice({
  name: "ingredients",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    getIngredientsSuccess: (
      state,
      action: PayloadAction<PaginatedIngredients>
    ) => {
      state.ingredients = action.payload.ingredients;
      state.pagination = action.payload.xPaginationDto;
    },
    getIngredientsFailure: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.errorMessage = action.payload;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    // @ts-ignore
    [getIngredientsAction.pending]: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = true;
    },
    // @ts-ignore
    [getIngredientsAction.fulfilled]: (state, action: any) => {
      const paginatedIngredients = action.payload as PaginatedIngredients;
      state.isLoading = false;
      state.ingredients = paginatedIngredients.ingredients;
      state.pagination = paginatedIngredients.xPaginationDto;
    },
    // @ts-ignore
    [getIngredientsAction.rejected]: (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false;
    },
  },
});
```

My state setup is above. My component setup is fairly simple as well:

```
const IngredientsList: React.FC = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { ingredients, pagination, renderCount } = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.ingredients
  );
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);

  const handlePagination =//some function to handle pagination

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("test");
    dispatch(
      getIngredientsAction({
        pageNumber: 1,
        pageSize: 5,
        sorts: "lastupdated",
      } as RequestOptionDto)
    );
  }, [dispatch, page]);

  return (
    <>
        <p>pagination value: {console.log(pagination)}</p>
        <p>page count: {pagination.totalPages}</p>
        {ingredients.map((x, index) => {
          return (
            <some component>
          );
        })}
      </Grid>

      <div>
        <Typography>Page: {page}</Typography>
        <Pagination
          count={pagination.totalPages}
          page={page}
          variant="outlined"
          onChange={handlePagination}
          color="secondary"
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default IngredientsList;
```

Comment: How is ingredientSlice used, I don't see it used anywhere? If it's to set state.ingredients then why is the initial value of state.ingredients an array?

Comment: @HMR I only included the relevant portion of the configuration. I followed the standard documentation (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#full-example) for configuring store. The slice reducer is exported and combined via a call to combineReducer() which in turn (i.e. the root reducer with all combined reducers) is passed to configureStore() which returns the store to me. This is then passed to the provider component that wraps my core component above. Ingredients is an array because it's a paginated list of objects, its empty initially because I have to wait for my API to respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like an idiot. So all my code above is correct. I didn't parse the value for pagination from my API into an actual object so it was coming through as a string instead of an actual object. As soon as I fixed that it resolved the issue.